# Subsequent requeries seem to use original query or another query entirely

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I first saw this with my edited [#Temporary tables and indexes work](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/5646/temporary-tables-and-indexes-work) and now see it with my simple [SELECT 1 then 2 Test](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59500/checking-caching).

The first query, whether it is cached or a new one (by ensuring you go to a database that hasn't run the query yet), works fine.

But if you then click `Run Query` again it is using another query. In the first case I think it is the original query before revisions were set up, and in the second one it is someone else's random query.

Comment: I was expecting this to be a mis-post from SO main when I first saw this!

Comment: deployed now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the response is returned, the URL that the form submits to sometimes needs to be updated. This was not one of those times, but it happened anyway, and the revision ID was replaced with the query set ID.

By [making sure the action needs](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=cd65610427c6af3f4f086322ae29a4780c9e6172) a query set ID added before appending it, this problem seems to go away.

Comment: I'll wait for this to go live before accepting it.