# Multiple Run Queries needed to get the result of an edited query in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, data-explorer

I don't know if this is related to my [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/every-second-failed-data-explorer-query-just-removes-the-last-error) [reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119329/subsequent-requeries-seem-to-use-original-query-or-another-query-entirely), but currently when you edit a query in SEDE the changes are ignored by the first `Run Query` (whether it be a valid query or an error).

The next `Run Query` seems to perform correctly. Subsequent attempts may fail to display errors, probably related to the [previous report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/every-second-failed-data-explorer-query-just-removes-the-last-error).

Comment: What do you mean by "the changes are ignored"?

Comment: @TimStone: It runs the previous unedited query.

Comment: Hmm...Can you reproduce this on every query? I tried this a few ways and it seemed to be working correctly for me.

Comment: While logged out I modified Sam's [top query that doesn't need a user id](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) to only admit questions with at least 20 down votes. The first `Run Query` still includes results with less than 20 down votes. Clicking again gets the right results. Again this is seems to be an IE8 issue. I don't see any problem with Chrome.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the additional info. I think I repro'ed this in the past, but then thought it was a temporary glitch because I couldn't get it to happen again. Either way, I'll figure out what's going wrong, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. I cannot reproduce it in the current version of SEDE. Please let me know if the problem remains for you.

Comment: Note that this was from 2 and half years ago, and I have now updated that machine that was running IE8 on Vista (much to the chagrin of my father). I still have a WinXP IE8, but I cannot repro either.

Comment: @MarkHurd glad to hear there's no repro on XP IE8... and also, I can't believe you still have an XP IE8 box. :D

Comment: I use it mainly as an email reader, because I still have Outlook Express running on it.

Comment: @MarkHurd nice, I do miss it in some ways. Solid e-mail client.